# Python/Pandas: Read csv with a (Python-) List

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So I saved data in the following format in a csv

vendor1,product,[['rating', 'review_text', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 21, 0, 0)], ['rating2', 'review2_text', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 29, 0, 0)]]

for several rows. The format is `string, string, list`.
The list can be of variable length. Within that list are lists conatining the data I want to work with in pandas. For example, I want to count reviews on a given day across products (rows). I thought I could just import this via `pandas.read_csv(...)`. The delimiter would of course be the comma, but the result is weird, breaking up the list across commata, leaving the commata intended for the split alone.

The intended format after import should be

(line 1) vendor1 product reviewlist

That way I could look for dates in column three and sum them up.
Any ideas how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the csv format understands arrays. I'd consider formatting the data differently.

If you are set on the 3 attributes with the third being an array, perhaps you could make it a string and use python's `eval` to get the array variable. Be careful here though.. as `eval` can have damaging consequences. Only use this if you have full control of the input

For input csv file containing (note the `"` around the array):

```
vendor,product,reviewlist
vendor1,product,"[['rating', 'review_text', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 21, 0, 0)], ['rating2', 'review2_text', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 29, 0, 0)]]"
```

a python script like:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime 

f = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

for index, row in f.iterrows():
    as_array = eval(row['reviewlist'])
```

would give you a array of arrays variable to manipulate